Creating multiple Excel workbooks from CSV data using Query Tables - why don't the format parameters take effect?
I need to import many (like, over 100) French-language, semicolon delimited CSV files to Excel and I got a little lazy about doing the conversion manually, and I sought a way to automate it. I'm using a MacBook (Apple silicon if it matters) so I can't use the built-in PowerQuery feature for this, unfortunately. I know nothing about VBA, so what was a measure of convenience spiraled out of control. Luckily up to this point I've been served well by my own stubbornness and Google -- I ended up operating off of this solution posted on Reddit. It ended up needing edits to actually function in current-year. Here's what I ended up with:
Sub Select_File_Or_Files_Mac()
    Dim MyPath As String
    Dim MyScript As String
    Dim MyFiles As String
    Dim MySplit As Variant
    Dim N As Long
    Dim Fname As String
    Dim mybook As Workbook

    On Error Resume Next

    MyFiles = AppleScriptTask("excelCSVselect.scpt", "select_files", "")
    On Error GoTo 0

    If MyFiles <> "" Then
        With Application
            .ScreenUpdating = False
            .EnableEvents = False
        End With
    MySplit = Split(MyFiles, Chr(10))
    
        For N = LBound(MySplit) To UBound(MySplit)

            'Get file name only and test if it is open
            Fname = Right(MySplit(N), Len(MySplit(N)))
'            - InStrRev(MySplit(N), _
'             ":", , 1))
            
                On Error Resume Next
                Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MySplit(N))
                On Error GoTo 0
             Next
             
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add( _
        Connection:="TEXT;" & Fname, _
        Destination:=Range("A1"))
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 65001
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = True

'        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
End With
           
              End If

End Sub



That excelCSVselect.scpt AppleScript has almost the exact same functionality as the reddit post's MacScript function. Cobbled together from multiple online sources. It allows you to select multiple .csv but converts it to a list with POSIX filepaths i.e. not using colons:
on convertListToString(theList, theDelimiter)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to theDelimiter
    set theString to theList as string
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
    return theString
end convertListToString

on select_files()
    set filelist to {}
    set CSV_files to choose file with prompt "Pick CSV Files to convert" with multiple selections allowed
    
    repeat with a in CSV_files
        set end of filelist to (POSIX path of a as string)
    end repeat
    return convertListToString(filelist, "\n")
end select_files

select_files()

The problem? All of the formatting that's supposed to be handled by the QueryTables.Add function isn't actually happening. I get a new workbook for each CSV but each CSV row is an ugly block. As far as I can tell, .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = True isn't getting run. The other big important thing is making sure the French special characters are getting displayed correctly. Theoretically, .TextFilePlatform = 65001 should be doing that; it's not. The other unideal thing happening is that I think the program is getting stuck somehow in that last section because after running it I can't get back into the VBA project anymore without quitting the Excel worksheet.
As I've said above, I have little to no idea what I'm doing. But I was looking at the Microsoft documentation and thinking maybe one of those QueryTable dot properties (e.g. .BackgroundQuery) was extraneous and messing with the output. I no longer think that is the case, and by removing too many of those methods I earned myself a mysterious 400 error I could not fix so I just left them be. I think it had something to do with the refresh process. Not that I understand what that means! :')

Upgrade your Excel version to one that can use power query.

You should try to circumvent the issue that prevents you from using Power Query. You should be able to solve this just by using Power Query without delving into the depths of the M-Language. Otherwise, since you don't know anything about VBA, you are asking for a turnkey solution.

@Storax I would have to get a new computer to do this. It's an operating system compatibility issue, not an Excel version issue. The Mac version of Excel, unless I'm mistaken, can only open one file at a time using PowerQuery.

I've never heard about such an incompatibility, but on the other hand, I do not have a Mac. So, I'm afraid I am not of any help here

FWIW, the corresponding applescript command open text file won't split the csv into columns either… unless you use comma. Of course, this may compromise the text.

On a separate note… do I understand that you can automatically process one file at a time (using PowerQuery)? If so, can you not just feed excel a single file at a time and go through them all that way?

@Mockman You don't even need PowerQuery. I use the Legacy "From Text" option to import a CSV and I specify UTF-8, semicolon delimited that way. Comes out perfect. Pretty easy, just tedious to do 200 times.

I misunderstood then. I had thought that you'd found a way to automate the processing of a single file. What if you just script the importation of each file and then split every row with 'text to columns' on the semicolon?

After (unwisely) spending my whole day solving this problem, I managed to get the field separation working almost 100% the way I wanted it to!
I didn't realize the linked solution was doing two things at once - that original Reddit poster opened a new workbook with Workbooks.Open when they actually wanted to load the data into a sheet.

Sub Select_File_Or_Files_Mac()
    Dim MyFiles As String
    Dim MySplit As Variant
    Dim N As Long
    Dim Fname As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim newData As QueryTable

    On Error Resume Next
    MyFiles = AppleScriptTask("excelCSVselect.scpt", "select_files", "")
    On Error GoTo 0

    If MyFiles <> "" Then
        With Application
            .ScreenUpdating = False
            .EnableEvents = False
        End With

        MySplit = Split(MyFiles, Chr(10))
        For N = LBound(MySplit) To UBound(MySplit)
            'Get file name only
            Fname = Right(MySplit(N), Len(MySplit(N)))
            Set ws = Worksheets.Add
            Set newData = ws.QueryTables.Add( _
                        Connection:="TEXT;" & Fname, _
                        Destination:=ws.Range("A1"))
            
            
    
  
            With newData
                .BackgroundQuery = False ' Change to False to prevent freezing
                .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
                .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
                .TextFileStartRow = 1
                .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
                .TextFilePlatform = 65001
                .PreserveFormatting = True
                .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = True
                .FieldNames = True
                .RowNumbers = False
                .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
                .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
                .SaveData = True
                .AdjustColumnWidth = True
                .RefreshPeriod = 0 ' No refresh period
            End With
            DoEvents ' Allow Excel to process events
        Next N

        With Application
            .ScreenUpdating = True
            .EnableEvents = True
        End With
    End If
End Sub


However, I still for the life of cannot get the special characters encoded correctly. I read something can happen where Excel just ignores UTF-8 encoding and uses UTF-16LE. I will choose to believe that is happening to cope.
Whatever the reason may be, since it was ultra important to get the special characters right to read the French text, I just used Python/Pandas to do it instead. Went a lot smoother. (Maybe should have started with that.) ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
